# Show a datagrid in a dockable window

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to show a list as a datagrid full of strings in a dockable window.

I can bind the list to the datagrid but I can't for the life of me get the datagrid to show in the dockable window.

I have the datagrid modifier as public

Any ideas?

```
public class NotLabelled : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
{
    public static IDockableWindow s_dockWindow;

    public NotLabelled()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        UID dockWinId = new UIDClass();

        dockWinId.Value = ThisAddIn.IDs.ResultsWindow;
        s_dockWindow = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(dockWinId);

        s_dockWindow.Show(!s_dockWindow.IsVisible());

        ResultsWindow.CheckForRoadsNotLabelled();
    }

    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        Enabled = ArcMap.Application != null;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Designer class of the dockable window add-in. It contains user interfaces that
/// make up the dockable window.
/// </summary>
public partial class ResultsWindow : UserControl
{
    public static List<string> AnnoList = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> StreetList = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> NotLabeled = new List<string>();

    public ResultsWindow(object hook)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Hook = hook;

        // load other data
        // ie xml data
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Host object of the dockable window
    /// </summary>
    public object Hook
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation class of the dockable window add-in. It is responsible for 
    /// creating and disposing the user interface class of the dockable window.
    /// </summary>
    public class AddinImpl : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.DockableWindow
    {
        public static ResultsWindow m_windowUI;

        public static List<string> NotLabeled = new List<string>();

        public AddinImpl()
        {
        }

        protected override IntPtr OnCreateChild()
        {
            m_windowUI = new ResultsWindow(this.Hook);
            return m_windowUI.Handle;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (m_windowUI != null)
                m_windowUI.Dispose(disposing);

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}  

public static void LoadGrid(IList<string> notlabeled)
{
    DataGridView dgResults = new DataGridView();

    dgResults.Rows.Clear();
    dgResults.Columns.Clear();
    dgResults.Refresh();

    dgResults.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

    dgResults.DataSource = NotLabeled; // notlabeled is binded to dgResults

    dgResults.Show(); // doesnt work
}
```

Comment: You've just ask a how long is a piece of string question! You have not shown us _any_ code about the dockable Window. How have you created it, what have you done, does the window show but not the grid? You need to provide more information if you want help.